# Make dynamics crm available from the net

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have installed dynamics crm on my computer in windows server 2012, and it works for me form my machine.
I want now to make available in the net from remote machine, so a user can connect to it from the net.
Is it possible and how can I dot that pleased?

Comment: Dynamics CRM is just a website, simply follow plenty of tutorials about hosting a website on a server (it's really basics of web development and understanding how network works, this is not a valid StackOverflow question).

Comment: @Alex it was clear for me that this is only a kind of "demo/dev/dummy" environment, so install CRM on local machine and make your colleagues able to access it, not a real deployment, so "correct" deployment is simply an overkill. You simply treat CRM as normal website with windows authentication, which is really simple and well explained in many tutorials out there. Maybe I misinterpreted the question, that's what comments are for I guess...

Answer (score 2):

Best practice would be to install ADFS and configure it with a valid SSL certificate, you'd then be able to reach your CRM from the outside world using an url like `https://yourorgname.yourdomain.com`

You'll need both a valid (*not* self-signed, you have to buy it) SSL certificate and to publish your URL on public DNS (which probably requires money too).

Documentation of the procedure is quite extensive, including it in this answer would not be appropriate: you can read it on MSDN with all details.

If following the best practice doesn't suit you, you can follow any procedure to make a website available to the outside world (CRM *is* a website after all, however complex).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex.
Is there any other way(without buying anything) to make it available for users from a remote machine like just giving them access to the server so as they can only go to the site by typing servername:port in their browser?

Comment: If the best practice doesn't suit you, you can treat CRM like any website and make it available in a number of ways (amended answer to include this remark)

Answer (score 1):

ADFS is the only supported way of exposing Dynamics CRM application in the internet. 
Another solutions are of course possible however you may meet some problems (for example in case of reporting services authentication or integration with Sharepoint document repository) when using them.

Did you consider using Dynamics 365 Online? 30-days trail is free.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamics on primes access out of intranet, Need to implement ADFS (IFD). If this is only for some time of demo purpose and if have public IP. Then you can host the MSCRM website on this public IP.